# Update array with strong parameters Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm receiving a JSON object and nested array via a Rails 4 api with params like so:

```
{
  "token" => "123"
  "lessons" => [
     {
         "token_id" => "j12l3n123",
         "attr_1" => "hello",
         "attr_2" = "is it me you're looking for"
     },
     {
         "token_id" => "j12l",
         "attr_1" => "Nope",
         "attr_3" = "You're not."
     }
  ]
}
```

And I have a controller like so:

```
def update_all
    #fetch collection with one db hit
    token_ids = params[:lessons].map{|l| l[:token_id]}
    @lessons = Lesson.where(token_id: token_ids)

    params[:lessons].each do |l|
       lesson = @lessons.detect { |lesson| lesson.token_id == l[:token_id] }
       # How do I update the record with strong params?
       lesson.update_attributes(lesson_params)
    end
end

private

def lesson_params
    params.permit(
     :attr_1,
     :attr_2,
     :attr_3
    )
end
```

How do i update each record with the right object in the array, and use strong parameters to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def update_all
    lesson_params.each do |l|
      lesson = Lesson.where(token_id: l[:token_id]).first
      lesson.update_attributes(l)
    end
end

private

def lesson_params
    params.require(:lessons).map do |l|
        ActionController::Parameters.new(l.to_hash).permit(
            :attr_1,
            :attr_2,
            :attr_3
        )
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`def lesson_params
    params.permit(:token, lessons: [:token_id, :attr_1, :attr_2, :attr_3 ])
 end`

in Controller something like following

`def update_all
    lesson_params[:lessons].each do |lesson_param|
       lesson = Lesson.find(lesson_param[:token_id])
       lesson.update_attributes(lesson_param)
  end
end`

Comment: How do I use this in the controller?

Comment: Didn't work for me, thank you for taking the time to answer. In any case, I've already found solution that works and have posted an answer.